# How to draw a sketch boundary or pencil boundary use GPUImage like this?

Tags: ios, gpuimage

How to draw a sketch boundary or pencil boundary use GPUImage like this? The result is not good when i use a mask picture.So, i think this is a custom filter,but i don't kown how to implement it?I was puzzled for two weeks.any one can help me...
the result like this(left is the PM needed, right is mine):[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7mnT.png)

the origianl picture and mask picture is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDICP.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fYxF.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey xue looking to your problem I think you should use SketchFilter or Thresholdsketchfilter and play with values to get your desired output, but as you are asking for masking , I'm attaching a code, where I'm using Dissolve to blend two images.

```
func addColorBlending(withImage : UIImage) {

        let blendImageFilter = DissolveBlend()
        blendImageFilter.mix = 0.3

        let blendImage = PictureInput(image: withImage)
        blendImage.processImage()
        blendImage.addTarget(blendImageFilter)

        let imageToBlendOn = PictureInput(image: self.processingModel.pencileDefaultImage)
        imageToBlendOn.processImage()
        imageToBlendOn.addTarget(blendImageFilter)

        let pictureOutput = PictureOutput()
        pictureOutput.imageAvailableCallback = { imageData in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.handAndFootImageView.image = imageData
                self.processingModel.blendedImage = imageData
            }
        }

        blendImageFilter.addTarget(pictureOutput)

    }
```

Here you can tweak **blendImageFitler.mix** property to get your desired output.
Hope it Helps you.